How to optimally transfer between nodes when each connection can only handle a certain number of things at a time?
Let's begin with a picture:

I am currently making a turn-based strategy game set in space where you can settle colonies  and have to transfer minerals from the colonies ("foo", "bar", "baz", and "qux" in the image) back to the capital ("destination" in the image). All transportation is abstractly represented by numbers:

Star is the capital and the destination for all minerals.
Circles are colonies ("nodes").
Lines are connections between colonies.
Blue numbers inside the circles are how many minerals each colony is producing each turn.
Green numbers next to the lines are the maximum capacity for that connection.

The problem I'm having is creating an algorithm that can properly distribute the produced minerals between connections in such a way that the maximum number of minerals reach the capital. My current algorithm is very naïve and runs into the following scenario:

foo wants to transfer its 3 minerals. Since both connections (foo <==> baz and foo <==> qux) are both capable of transferring 3 minerals one is chosen at random, in this case the foo <==> qux connection is chosen.
bar wants to transfer its 3 minerals. It transfers them to qux through that connection.
qux now has 7 minerals (1 start + 3 from foo + 3 from bar). Since the qux <==> destination connection can only handle 4 minerals it only transfers 4 minerals, leaving 3 stuck in qux. Note that it cannot transfer these remaining minerals back to foo since the connection foo <==> qux has already transported its maximum capacity of 3 minerals in step 1!

However as we can see from the image, at step 1 (foo <==> qux transfer) if foo had chosen to transfer to baz instead we would not have had 3 minerals left over in step 3. This is also where I've hit a roadblock, I am unable to come up with an algorithm that can properly distribute the minerals in such a way that no minerals get "stuck". I managed to create an algorithm that can brute-force every single connection but this algorithm is brutally slow since my game can have upwards of ~100 nodes with ~6 connections each.
I've tried to think about this solution as a pathfinding problem ("people trying to reach a destination but the roads can only handle a certain number of people"). I feel like someone else should have had this problem but unfortunately I can't find any literature or mention this rephrased problem either!
Anyone have any ideas of where to begin?

This sounds like the Maximum Flow Problem — are algorithms for solving that suitable for your needs? There's also some related Q&A that may have some useful inspirations.

@DMGregory Thank you! It's definitely in the right direction. Now I just need to find an algorithm that supports multiple sources + single sink. If you happen to know one feel free to share otherwise I'll google-fu my way there :P

You can introduce a fictitious source node that totals up the values in each of your actual source nodes, with a one-way edge joining the virtual source to each actual source, having capacity equal to that source's stockpile. Now you've converted a graph with multiple sources to an equivalent graph with a single source, and you can map the solution for that augmented graph back to a valid solution for your original graph.

A related body of work/problems I worked on at uni are capacitated transshipment problems. Many of them are equivalent to network flow problems (or at least start out that way in complications are added), so you may find some additional resources searching for CTPs as well.
